# How to disable and put limits on checkboxes with radio button (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a radio-type button and a few checkboxes. I basically want to disable the checkboxes when I choose **Non-Exclusive** then limit the checkboxes to **2** if I choose **Package 1**.

Here's my ***html code:***

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="non-exclusive" id="non-exclusive" name="packages"> Non-Exclusive
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" value="package1" id="package1" name="packages"> Package 1
    </label>
    <label>
    <input type="radio" value="package2" id="package2" name="packages"> Package 2
    </label>
<br />
    <label><h2>Rice </h2></label>
    <br />
    <a style="color: darkred;">2 Choices</a>
    <br />
    <div class="checkboxfood">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Plain Rice (Mandatory)
      </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Buttered Rice
      </label>
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Garlic Rice
      </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Kimchi Rice
      </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Adobo Rice
      </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Yang Chow Rice
      </label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Shanghai Rice
      </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Bagoong Rice
      </label>
    </div>
```

I've tried this **javascript**:

```
$('#package1').on('change', function() {
$('.checkBoxes :checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
$(':checkbox:eq(0), :checkbox:eq(1), :checkbox:eq(2), :checkbox:eq(3), :checkbox:eq(4), :checkbox:eq(5)\n\
, :checkbox:eq(6), :checkbox:eq(7), :checkbox:eq(8), :checkbox:eq(9), :checkbox:eq(10), :checkbox:eq(11), :checkbox:eq(12)\n\
, :checkbox:eq(13), :checkbox:eq(14), :checkbox:eq(15)').prop('disabled', false);

});


$('#package2').on('change', function() {
$('.checkBoxes :checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
$(':checkbox:eq(0), :checkbox:eq(1)').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#non-exclusive').on('change', function() {
$('.checkBoxes :checkbox').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

It enables checkboxes but it won't limit it. Also if I press back to **Non-Exlusive** the checkboxes doesn't go back to being "disabled".

I've also tried this code:

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
   this.checked = false;
}
});
```

Which limits my checkboxes but isn't responsive to my radio buttons.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific problem? This is not a site to just post what you want and expect that we’ll just provide you with a solution.

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in the same post. Target a specific problem instead.

Comment: @31piy Well, all of the problems are connected into one.

Comment: Some of the classes in your jQuery selectors don't exist in the html. Create a [mcve] using your code and matching html

Comment: @charlietfl I changed the "single-checkbox" to "checkbox" and "checkboxes" and it still didn't work.

I just want to know if there is I a way where I can link both solutions into one whole code/string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase you are familiar with JQuery use this
To disable the checkboxes when you choose non-exclusive

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  if($(this).attr('id') == 'non-exclusive'){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled","disabled");
  } else {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
 });
```

To Limit the checkboxes to 2 when you choose package1

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
   //get the checked radio id
   var radio = $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id');

   if(radio == 'package1'){
      //check the number of the checked checkboxes
      if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2){
         //do what you want here  ex: display alert message
         this.checked=false;
         return false;
      }//end if
    }//end if
});
```

Of course you have to write more code to uncheck all boxes or implement your logic if the user choose package1 after he selects more than two checkboxes when package2 was selected before

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I need. I'll just add the missing codes.

Comment: Should use `prop()` not `attr()` for `'disabled'`

Comment: I'm glad it helped, happy coding ^^

Answer (score 0):

Following will do all you ask as well as uncheck any checkboxes greater than 2 if user changes to package 1 after selecting more than 2 in package 2

```js
var $checkboxes = $('.checkboxfood :checkbox'),
  $radios = $('.radios input:radio')


$radios.on('change', function(e) {
  if (this.value === 'non-exclusive') {
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', true)
  } else {
    $checkboxes.prop('disabled', false);
  }
  if (this.value == 'package1') {
    // leave only 2 checked 
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked:gt(1)').prop('checked', false)
  }
});

// only need to know if package 1 is checked when checkboxes are selected
$checkboxes.on('change', function(e){
  if($('#package1').is(':checked') && $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length >2){
    this.checked = false;
    console.log("Only 2 allowed for package 1")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="non-exclusive" id="non-exclusive" name="packages"> Non-Exclusive
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="package1" id="package1" name="packages"> Package 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="package2" id="package2" name="packages"> Package 2
  </label>
</div>


<br />
<label>
  <h2>Rice </h2></label>
<br />
<a style="color: darkred;">2 Choices</a>
<br />
<div class="checkboxfood">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Plain Rice (Mandatory)
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Buttered Rice
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Garlic Rice
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Kimchi Rice
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Adobo Rice
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Yang Chow Rice
  </label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Shanghai Rice
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Bagoong Rice
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using native JavaScript:

```js
 let q = document.getElementsByClassName('food');
  q = Array.from(q);

  // handle chacked event
  let packages = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="packages"]')
  packages = Array.from(packages);

  let foods = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'))
  foods = Array.from(foods);

  for (let pack in packages) {
    if (packages.hasOwnProperty(pack)) {
      packages[pack].onclick = function () {
        let choosedPack = this.value;

        if (choosedPack === 'non-exclusive') {
          q.forEach(function (item) {
            item.disabled = true;
          });
        } else if (choosedPack === 'package1') {
        
          q.forEach(function (item) {
            item.disabled = false;
          });

          q.forEach(function (item) {
            item.checked = false;
          });
   
          for (let food in foods) {
            if (foods.hasOwnProperty(food)) {
              foods[food].onclick = function () {
                if ((document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length) > 2) {
                  alert('More than 2 values!');
                  this.disabled = false;
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        

      }
    }

  }
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="non-exclusive" id="non-exclusive" name="packages"> Non-Exclusive
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="package1" id="package1" name="packages"> Package 1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" value="package2" id="package2" name="packages"> Package 2
</label>
<br />
<label><h2>Rice </h2></label>
<br />
<a style="color: darkred;">2 Choices</a>
<br />
<div class="checkboxfood">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Plain Rice (Mandatory)
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Buttered Rice
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Garlic Rice
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Kimchi Rice
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Adobo Rice
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Yang Chow Rice
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Shanghai Rice
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="food" value=""> Bagoong Rice
    </label>
</div>
```